# how to get raw deph camera image?

Tags: google-project-tango

How can I get raw depth image from tango, original, without preprocessing averageiation between frames, with all the noise as is?
We want to do preprocessing by ourselves.

We already can do the on xyzij callback, it is working, but not as we need.

We want to create point cloud by ourselves.

Maybe it is possible to hack tango somehow to get access to raw image, like disassemble the libtangoclient, or hack the hardware.

Is there someone at google I can contact about it?

Answer (score 0):

Tango does not provide access to depth image directly through Tango API. The approach I would go is to project those points onto camera's image plane, and perform upsampling to get a good result. It is the best way I know so far. Following links should help:

[upsample method](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/group/depth-interpolation-support#group___depth_interpolation_support_1ga03a4e39d813814d837c24216f3ee105d)

[rgb-depth-sync example code](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_rgb_depth_sync_example)

credits to [Jason Guo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3561953/jason-guo)

Comment: @ Atef Haouari - Did you make some progress on this issue which you can share?

Answer (score -1):

It's not a depth camera, but an infrared depth sensor that allow to retrieve a point cloud.

There are no raw image to extract. The only thing that you can do is to transform points on white pixels as shown on the bottom of this post:

https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/depth-perception